# JDBC - SQLITE Select to variable

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, resultset, executequery

I am trying to run a query / select statement and save it in a variable. I know how to get something specific from a specific column but not from counting rows.

This is working as I getting MYID specifically.

```
ResultSet MYIDrs = stmtCFG.executeQuery( "SELECT rowid, MYID from MYINDEX order by rowid desc limit 1;" );
MYID = MYIDrs.getString("MYID");
```

Now I am trying to count the rows that works in SQLite client but not in the jdbc as I can't figure out what to request.

this is what I have but is not resulting in what I am expecting.

```
ResultSet FILE_COUNTrs = stmtCFG.executeQuery( "SELECT count(*) from TABLE where MYID = '"+MYID+"';");
FILE_COUNT = FILE_COUNTrs.getString(?????);
```

problem or question is: What do I put in the ????? as I already tried everything.

I am expecting to see a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really sorry I found what I was looking for by assigning a name TOTAL

This is my code and it works...

```
ResultSet FILE_COUNTrs = stmtCFG.executeQuery( "SELECT count(*) AS TOTAL from TABLE where MYID = '"+MYID+"';");
FILE_COUNT = FILE_COUNTrs.getString("TOTAL");
```

Comment: That should not work, you need to call `FILE_COUNTrs.next()` before retrieving your value.

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong data type. COUNT(*) returns Integer type, Not String.

You can do like this without assigning a label for COUNT(*)

```
int FILE_COUNT = FILE_COUNTrs.getInt(1); // 1: is the column index of COUNT(*)
```